Sign in householder QR decomposition
This is my code for computing QR decomposition algorithm using house holding transforms.
from sympy import *

def qr(A):
    m, n = shape(A)

    QT = eye(m, m)
    R = A.copy()

    for k in range(n):
        x = R[k:m,k]
        sign = 1 if x[0,0] > 0 else -1
        e1 = zeros(m - k, 1)
        e1[0,0] = 1
        v = sign * sqrt((x.T * x)[0,0]) * e1 + x
        v /= sqrt((v.T * v)[0,0])
        H = eye(m - k) - 2 * v * v.T
        if k == 0:
            QT = H
        else:
            _QT = eye(m, m)
            _QT[k:m,k:m] = H
            QT = _QT * QT
        R[k:m,k:n] = H * R[k:m,k:n]

    return QT.T, R

A = Matrix([[1, 2], [3, 4]])

Q, R = qr(A)

assert A.equals(Q * R)

I am aware that the purpose of the line sign = 1 if x[0,0] > 0 else -1 is to ensure the numerical stability but it seems like when I change this line to sign = 1 or sign = -1, it does not affect the overall correctness of the algorithm. I wonder why.
This math.se post doesn't answer my question.

Indeed the set of matrices where you lose precision is small, but it exists. Try matrices that are small perturbations of diagonal matrices, e.g., of the identity matrix.

@LutzLehmann Actually, for this question, I am assuming that floating point numbers have infinite precision, not fintie precision.

Then of course you avoid the errors due to catastrophic cancellation and only have to care about division by zero.
